# Control-click does not change selection in IKImageBrowserView, right-click or two-finger-click does

Tags: macos, cocoa, mouse, ikimagebrowserview, trackpad

I added a context menu to an `IKImageBrowserView`.

When a user right-clicks (mouse) or two-finger-clicks (trackpad) an image in the `IKImageBrowserView`, *the selection changes to this image*, and the context menu appears.

When a user control-clicks (mouse or trackpad), *the selection does **not** change*, and the context menu appears.

As the context menu is relative to the selected image, I prefer, that the selection changes, when the context menu is invoked.

- Can I make the `IKImageBrowserView` change selection also on control-click (mouse and trackpad)?
- Can I attach the context menu not to the `IKImageBrowserView` but to a single element/image of an `IKImageBrowserView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a subclass of IKImageBrowserView and override `menuForEvent:`, you can accomplish this:

```
- (NSMenu *)menuForEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSUInteger idx = [self indexOfItemAtPoint:[self convertPoint:[event locationInWindow] fromView:nil]];

    if (idx == NSNotFound) {return nil;}

    if (![self.selectionIndexes containsIndex:idx]) {
        [self setSelectionIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:idx] byExtendingSelection:NO];

    }

    return self.menu;
}
```

Comment: This works in principle, but gives an error, when I click at an area within the IKImageBrowserView but outside of an actual image: `-[NSIndexSet initWithIndexesInRange:]: Range {9223372036854775807, 1} exceeds maximum index value of NSNotFound - 1`

Comment: Ok, `9223372036854775807` seems to be the value of `NSNotFound`, and I can just test `(idx != NSNotFound)` before changing the index. I updated your answer.

Comment: Ahh...I had adapted it from use in a tableView where rows couldn't be clicked between, and didn't try that on the IKImageBrowserView.